# check if date is valid

Tags: perl, datetime

In my program I have the user input a date in the format of "Month Day" (example May 25) and I want to be able to print an error message if it is an invalid date (example February 30).

So here's some code

```
$start_date = ARGV[0];
my $year = DateTime->now->year;                                          # adds a year to the date
my $date_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%Y %B %d', # YYYY Month DD
);
my $start_epoch = $date_parser->parse_datetime("$year $start_date")->epoch();
```

Right after this I need some kind of if statement right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the date is invalid, then the parser will return `undef`. You will see this quite quickly if you do:

```
my $start_date = "Feb 30";
my $year = DateTime->now->year;                                          # adds a year to the date
my $date_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%Y %B %d', # YYYY Month DD
);
my $start_epoch = $date_parser->parse_datetime("$year $start_date")->epoch();
```

The solution:

```
my $parsed =  $date_parser->parse_datetime("$year $start_date");
if ( not defined $parsed ) { print "Error - invalid date\n"; }
```

Comment: One other quick question. I want to add a check if the start date is at a later date than the end date. Can't I just say `if (start_epoch > end_epoch)`

Comment: In that case, you don't need to compare the `epoch` values at all. E.g.: `print "Earlier than now" if $parsed < DateTime->now;` - you can compare the `DateTime` objects directly.

Answer (score 0):

From [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=564594):

> ```
> use Time::Local;
> my $date = ' 19990230'; # 30th Feb 1999
> $date =~ s/\s+$//;
> $date =~ s/^\s*//;
> my ($year, $month, $day) = unpack "A4 A2 A2", $date;
> eval{ 
>     timelocal(0,0,0,$day, $month-1, $year); # dies in case of bad date
> + 
>     1;
> } or print "Bad date: $@";
> ```

This should do you justice

Comment: thanks, didn't really know how to do it, thought I had the hyperlink originally @Flexo